# Make JavaScript choose image and display it from an array (randomly)

Tags: javascript, html

With my code, I made an array for JavaScript to randomly choose an image and display it. But its not showing. Please help.

This is my code currently:

**HTML & JS**

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="icon" href="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41I+vcnXn-L._AC_UL600_SR600,600_.png" />
    <title>Noice Game</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img id="img1"  src="" alt="" /> 
    <button class="foodbtn" onclick="GetImage();" id="imagebtn">
        Begin!
      </button>
  <body>
<html>


<script>
function GetImage() 
{ 
    var imagearray= new Array("https://cdn.madeinturkeytours.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/vegan-cig-kofte.jpg","https://deih43ym53wif.cloudfront.net/large_spanakopita-greek-food_dd3bda740c.jpeg","https://static.toiimg.com/thumb/53099699.cms?width=1200&height=900","https://www.travelbuddies.info/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/tsuivan.jpg"); 
    var randomimagesrc = imagearray[Math.floor(Math.random() * imagearray.length)];    
    
} 

$("#img1").attr("src", imagearray[randomimagesrc]);
</script>

<style>
  #img1 {
      size: 400px;
      z-index: 1000;
  }

</style>
```

Comment: I don't see where Java is involved here.

Comment: you need to move `$("#img1").attr("src", imagearray[randomimagesrc]);` inside your function.  Also your script wants to before your end body tag and your style wants to be in the head and your body and html closing tags are opening tags

Comment: @connexo i wrote it in the <script> tags

Comment: java is not javascript

Comment: @Pete nooo I put them in separate files i just quickly compiled them together that's why its like that

Comment: yeah i know it not javascript, why?

Comment: @Evan — The second word in the question.

Comment: ohhh ok sorry..

Answer (score 0):

You need to move `$("#img1").attr(...)` inside the `GetImage()` function. Also, since you are accessing a random element in `randomimagesrc`, there is no need to do  `imagearray[randomimagesrc]` while setting the `src`.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <link rel="icon" href="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41I+vcnXn-L._AC_UL600_SR600,600_.png" />
  <title>Noice Game</title>
</head>

<body>
  <img id="img1" src="" alt="" />
  <button class="foodbtn" onclick="GetImage()" id="imagebtn">
        Begin!
      </button>

  <body>
    <html>


    <script>
      function GetImage() {
        var imagearray = new Array("https://cdn.madeinturkeytours.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/vegan-cig-kofte.jpg", "https://deih43ym53wif.cloudfront.net/large_spanakopita-greek-food_dd3bda740c.jpeg", "https://static.toiimg.com/thumb/53099699.cms?width=1200&height=900", "https://www.travelbuddies.info/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/tsuivan.jpg");
        var randomimagesrc = imagearray[Math.floor(Math.random() * imagearray.length)];
        $("#img1").attr("src", randomimagesrc);

      }
    </script>

    <style>
      #img1 {
        size: 400px;
        z-index: 1000;
      }
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have provided change src sript outside the `GetImage()` function and when you already have created new variable which is random, then you can use it directly in `randomimagesrc`

```js
function GetImage() 
{ 
    var imagearray= new Array(
    "https://cdn.madeinturkeytours.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/vegan-cig-kofte.jpg",
    "https://deih43ym53wif.cloudfront.net/large_spanakopita-greek-food_dd3bda740c.jpeg",
    "https://static.toiimg.com/thumb/53099699.cms?width=1200&height=900",
    "https://www.travelbuddies.info/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/tsuivan.jpg"
    ); 
    var randomimagesrc = imagearray[Math.floor(Math.random() * imagearray.length)];    
  $("#img1").attr("src", randomimagesrc);    
}
```

```css
#img1 {
      size: 400px;
      z-index: 1000;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="img1"  src="" alt="" /> 
<button class="foodbtn" onclick="GetImage();" id="imagebtn">
    Begin!
</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

The problems you had:

1. You had `html lang="en">`. You forgot to add an extra `<` before that code.
2. Secondly, I think it would be better if the script and style tag were inside the html tag.
3. I recommend using HTML DOM over jQuery.
4. Also put the HTML dom inside the function.

Now you're done!

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="icon" href="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41I+vcnXn-L._AC_UL600_SR600,600_.png" />
    <title>Noice Game</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img id="img1"  src="" alt="" /> <br>
    <button class="foodbtn" onclick="GetImage();" id="imagebtn">
        Begin!
      </button>
  <body>
<script>
function GetImage() 
{ 
    var imagearray= new Array("https://cdn.madeinturkeytours.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/vegan-cig-kofte.jpg","https://deih43ym53wif.cloudfront.net/large_spanakopita-greek-food_dd3bda740c.jpeg","https://static.toiimg.com/thumb/53099699.cms?width=1200&height=900","https://www.travelbuddies.info/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/tsuivan.jpg"); 
    var randomimagesrc = imagearray[Math.floor(Math.random() * imagearray.length)];   
document.getElementById('img1').src = randomimagesrc;
    
} 

$("#img1").attr("src", imagearray[randomimagesrc]);
</script>

<style>
  #img1 {
      size: 400px;
      z-index: 1000;
  }

</style>
<html>
```

Here's your new code.

Edit: Forgot to add that you can make the picture fixed size, so you don't need to chase the button.

```
<style>
img#img1 {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
}
</style>
```